# How can I getElement with selenium using href?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get the element on a webpage using selenium but it only has an href which I can't reference, every time I do, I get an error that the element wasn't found.

This is the line I am trying to access

`<a href="javascript:top.menusubasp('/apps/Registration/');">Registration</a>`

This is my code

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/apps/Registration/']")).click();`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried finding it by its text

**xpath**

```
//a[text()='Registration']
```

**LinkText**

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Registration"));
```

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if you face any problems